# Backup/Restore database for SQL Server continuous integration testing

Tags: sql-server-2008, ant, continuous-integration, bamboo

What is the best way to restore a SQL Server database on our testing server from a snapshot taken in production.  Database is running on Windows Server 2003 with SQL Server 2008

We are using Bamboo along with Ant scripts for continuous integration running on Ubuntu.

I want to be able to restore the database to a backup taken from production and apply the latest update scripts.

Any advise is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please mark an answer as accepted if it helped you out!

Answer (score 0):

DbUnit can probably help you.

http://www.dbunit.org/